# Angular 6 Form Validation - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, validation

I seem to be missing something in my code. Please assist! In my browser console, I'm seeing "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

HTML Component
[image: HTML PORTION]

COMPONENT.ts File
[image: component]

ERROR MESSAGE
[image: Console Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define reference `#f` to your form, change as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="newUserForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSumbit)="createUser()">
```

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Thanks so much! That definitely was the missing piece!

Answer (score 1):

in routing module you probably missed out routing conf check it once, as i got the same problem add `{path:'new', component : RecipeEditComponent}` in recipe children

Answer (score 0):

use this in component.ts file
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'...
bczz you used rectiveform method in html code

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was a difference between the two. I decided to reformat my code to Template form validation :)